# What do you mean by endurance of a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design

What is the role that endurance of a capacitor  plays in circuit design

Comment: It is one of the factors which determines the MTBF of the product.

Comment: Look up Arrhenius effect and then see how few hours caps are rated at 85'C and 105'C for high rel e-caps then factor self heating from ripple current and d.f.

Comment: @Oldfart MTBF =! Product endurance. Look it up! An AA battery may have millions if not trillions of hours of MTBF due to their robust and simple nature yet only Basra a few hours under load before they are depleted.